# How do you find out the difference between workstations and servers on the network?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, active-directory

I know how to get the machines on a server using the System.DirectoryServices network. 
The issue is that I would like to ignore workstations/computers on the network and only retrieve servers.

In case someone says to check the OS version, the problem with getting a Win NT family OS version number is that each number may correspond to both a server and non-server OS (such as NT version 6.1 referring both to Win 7 and Win Server 2008 R2).

Here is my basic test class:

```
namespace Project1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             List<string> list = Class1.GetComputersOnNetwork();           
        }

        public static List<string> GetComputersOnNetwork()
        {
            string fileName = "networkcomputers.txt";  

            // Delete the file if it exists.
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
            }

            // Create the file.
            System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName, 1024);

            StreamWriter strwr = new StreamWriter(fs);

            int i = 0;
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");           
            foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
            {                   
                if ((computers.Name != "Schema"))
                {
                    i++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Machine Number " + i + ": " + computers.Name);
                    strwr.WriteLine("Machine Number " + i + ": " + computers.Name);
                    list.Add(computers.Name);
                }           
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is RPC enabled on the servers and accessible to your application?  For instance, you could query the remote machine's registry with RPC.

Comment: By "server", you mean "running a server SKU of Windows" and not any particular kind of behavior or installed services?

Comment: mellamokb
I'll look into that.


@MNGwinn
Yes, that is what I am referring to.

Comment: Are you in a Domain?  Have you considered using Active Directory for this?

Comment: I am using Active Directory for this. What I need to do is differentiate between servers and workstations, by OS. The problem is there is no operatingsystem property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going at the `operatingSystemVersion` property, look at the `operatingSystem` property. That'll give you the name of the SKU. You'll need to know which are server OS versions and which aren't - there's no `IsServer` boolean. Depending on how they're named, you may be able to do a wildcard search on `operatingSystemVersion` to find computers that have a `operatingSystemVersion` that contains the string "server".

Comment: For whatever reason, there is no operating system property (it's probably blocked on machines on this domain), but thanks a lot for the help anyways.

Comment: I ended up using WMI commands from the System.Management namespace. That took care of it :).

Answer (score 2):

You can read the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallationType`.

The key is:

- "Server" if this PC is running Windows Server (e.g. Windows Server 2012).
- "Client" if this PC is running Windows Desktop (e.g. Windows 8.1).

This registry key is quite easy to read using any language such as C#.

For more info, see article entitled "[distinguish between server os and workstation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ejarvi/archive/2004/06/08/151162.aspx)".

***Update***

Link is dead, use archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140502101009/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ejarvi/archive/2004/06/08/151162.aspx

Copying from this page:

> ejarvi 8 Jun 2004 3:47 PM 9 I maintain a script in our test harness
>   that autodetects and reports back the OS version of the machine under
>   test.  I couldn't tell if I was running XP SP1 or XP SP2 - so I had a
>   kludge that used spcheck from the reskit.  But the real problem was
>   that I was getting most info using ver from the cmd shell but on
>   Windows 2000 couldn't tell the difference between Professional and
>   Server.  I was able to find all this info in the registry so I ripped
>   out the hacks and now I'm just reading from there.  If anyone else out
>   there is trying to do the same thing, here's where I get the
>   information from (all are in HKLM):
>
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName (Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2003, Microsoft Windows XP, Microsoft Windows 2000)
>
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CDSVersion (Service Pack
>   1, Service Pack 2, ...)
>
> And to distinguish between Pro and Server on Windows 2000:
>   SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions\ProductType (WinNT,
>   ServerNT)
>
> I didn't actually use it in my case but if you're looking for more of
>   a prepackaged tool to do this type of thing, DtWinVer at
>   http://www.codeproject.com/system/dtwinver.asp also looks promising.

Comment: That link is dead

Comment: Lucky there is archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20140502101009/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ejarvi/archive/2004/06/08/151162.aspx